# How to fit textbox width with a set of columns in a grid?

Tags: wpf, textbox, grid, width, column-width

Supose I have a grid with 4 columns and want to put a textbox in the second column and span it to the last column. How could I fit the textbox width to be as wide as the 3 last columns?

I have tried something with Borders, but it didn't work.

```xml
<Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7):

Give TextBox some width or make ColumnDefinition width as * instead of Auto. It is spanning till the last column but just you are not able to see it as the width is Auto.

Comment: It didn't work... It doesn't depend on the column width. I could set the columns width as any value, I just want my textbox to have the same width of the three last columns together.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos You need to make all column definitions `Width="*"`, not just the column the `TextBox` is in.

Comment: Well, it worked as @Dipesh and @Rachel said. But - for a reason I don't know - it didn't work in my real code (with other things), the `Grid.ColumnSpan` didn't work as it was suposed to do. I have already other `Textboxes` in other rows at the same `Grid`
Do you know why this could happen?

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos It's impossible to know without seeing your real code. Perhaps open another SO question with a simplified example of your code that produces the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Right now the last 3 columns are fitting the text box as the width is auto.

```
  <Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: It should be noted that a Width of `Auto` means `"only take up the space needed to render the controls inside these columns"`, while a Width of `*` means `"split the space evenly between all * sized columns"`. So Balam's example is splitting the space evenly between 4 columns, and stretching the `TextBox` across 3 of them, so the final width of the `TextBox` will be 3/4ths of your Grid's Width.

Answer (score 3):

As [Dipesh Bhatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482751/293712) has rightly put in his answer that solution to your problem is to put * or something specific as width for columns.

What happens in your example is auto width for column says "**take as much is required**" hence it takes very little width, as empty textbox will require very very small width, which is hardly visible.

A * in width for column says "**acquire whatever space is available**" this will increase width of column hence it will give more space to textbox.

This means you have already achieved what you wanted but its hardly visible due to minimal width of columns.

Comment: Just as an extra note - your textbox should have a HorizontalAlignment of 'Stretch'.  It should by default, but just in case...

Comment: @Liz: Agreed. Didn't mention as this is default behavior.